# Createjs dispatching an event freezes the application

Tags: javascript, createjs

I'm having a problem when I have many events dispatched, the application seems to freeze but the browser seems to be still responsive.

I believe to be the dispatching of these events because of evidence found when using chrome profiler.

I tried stopping the propagation (stoppropagation and stopimmediatepropagation) when the event has been handled but the app still continues to freeze.

Is there a max quantity of events which can be fired or handled?

Any Ideas?

thanks

Comment: It is more likely caused by whatever is catching the event. Freezing like this could be a result of an infinite loop. Does the event handler do something that might cause the event to fire again? Can you post code?

Comment: The thing is it is a big app which I am porting from as3. The problem occurs when a big element which contains some other elements is dragged, all these inner elements must be moved along this container. I'm dispatching an event and handling it in the inner elements to move them along the container. When it has a few elements the app works fine, it it when there are many that the app freezes, it doesnt crash the tab, but freezes the "createjs canvas". Profiling the thing didnt help much.. I cant seem to find where the thing is getting stuck..